# Display specific service after AWS Console login

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, saml-2.0, google-workspace

I have configured AWS to be use Google as an IdP with SAML logins. AWS is the RP.

I'd like to send a specific role directly to the service they are concerned with. The users in Questions are only concerned with billing and seem to be overwhelmed having to choose among the many AWS services.

Is there a way, with SAML logins, to specify that

- users in the e.g. "billing" group should end up directly at: https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home
- users in "DBA" group should end up directly at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home

when **specifically used with G-Suite**?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure your identity provider, you should be able to send an additional RelayState parameter. More information can be found [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=313858).

Comment: Thanks, I do know about the RelayState but I don't see any option how to configure this in G-Suite. Less so in a dynamic manner

Comment: I believe the best place to start would be the start url option in GSuite, as described here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/desktop-and-application-streaming/setting-up-g-suite-saml-2-0-federation-with-amazon-appstream-2-0/.